# Linker error in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I can't figure out this linker error in Visual Studio C++ 2010 for hours:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double * * __cdecl   
Matrix::rotx(double)" (?rotx@Matrix@@SAPAPANN@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Documents 
and Settings\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\Assignment_01\Assignment_01\Assignment_01.obj Assignment_01
```

I am not sure what is the problem, this started happening once I separated my Matrix class in separate
header and cpp files. Must be something about how I include files.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the .cpp file part of your VS project?

Comment: Is it so hard not to answer if you don't know the answer?

Comment: Vlad, yes I have both a .cpp and .h files.

Comment: You probably have declared à function in your header file, which you use in main, and have not implemented it in your .cpp file.

Comment: Hmm, nope, it is implemented. Want me to send code guys? It is a small project

Comment: It might help if you posted the .h file and at least the part of the .cpp file containing `rotx`. A typo there could give you the error.

Comment: Ok, just a sec, I will send the project here... thanks

Comment: Did you forget the `Matrix::` qualifier for your function in the .cpp file?

Comment: Haha wow Tibo, that's it, problem solved. Chesus how could I miss that :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a function declared in your header file / class declaration that's not implemented in your .cpp file. Make sure you defined the method `rotx(double`) in your matrix file.